Sabre: Bargin Finder Max Rest api - Invalid Request
I am currently trying to run BarginFinderMax at https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com//v4/offers/shop. . for sabre api. The request header consists of Authorization header consisting of Bearer {token}.
The current request body is like this:
{
    "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
        "POS": {
            "Source": [
                {
                    "PseudoCityCode": "PCC_CODE",
                    "RequestorID": {
                        "ID": "1",
                        "Type": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "OriginDestinationInformation": [
            {
                "DepartureDateTime": "2024-10-01T00:00:00",
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "KTM"
                },
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "DXB"
                },
                "RPH": "1"
            },
            {
                "DepartureDateTime": "2024-10-28T00:00:00",
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "DXB"
                },
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "KTM"
                },
                "RPH": "2"
            }
        ],
        "TravelerInfoSummary": {
            "AirTravelerAvail": [
                {
                    "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
                        {
                            "Code": "ADT",
                            "Quantity": 1,
                            "Changeable": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "Version": "4"
    }
}

The above request has following error response:

{
    "groupedItineraryResponse": {
        "version": "6.3.0",
        "messages": [
            {
                "severity": "Info",
                "type": "SERVER",
                "code": "GCA14-ISELL-TN-00-2024-10-00-9LFK",
                "text": "27131"
            },
            {
                "severity": "Info",
                "type": "WORKERTHREAD",
                "code": "TRANSACTIONID",
                "text": "7364989799406789611"
            },
            {
                "severity": "Error",
                "type": "SERVER",
                "code": "INVALID",
                "text": "Bad request",
                "value": "Invalid request"
            },
            {
                "severity": "Error",
                "type": "MAIN",
                "code": "INVALIDREQ",
                "text": "Incorrect GIR response schema version used"
            },
            {
                "severity": "Error",
                "type": "ERR",
                "code": "ERR",
                "text": "Error during Processing"
            }
        ],
        "statistics": {
            "itineraryCount": 0
        }
    }
}

I tried changing the version for url and body to v2 in which case i get an error.
{
    "status": "NotProcessed",
    "type": "Application",
    "errorCode": "ERR.2SG.CLIENT.INVALID_REQUEST",
    "timeStamp": "2024-09-26T10:10:47.291Z",
    "message": "Client invalid path, not found in rest table"
}

Also i have checked the docs to see if anything is missing but i can't seem to find one.
